# Does it mean that man hasn't done two exercises?

Tags: prepositions

Sentence:

> He's done all of it but two exercises

Does it mean that man hasn't done two exercises?

He's done all of it **but two exercises** = He's done all of it **except two exercises**

Comment: Yes.­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're using is

> all **but**
>   everything **but**

which means "*everything else* ***except***"...

> all **but** the kitchen sink
>   *everything except the kitchen sink*

So your understanding is correct

> He did all the exercises **except** for two of them, two exercises have not been done.